# AWS ec2 instance audits

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to take audit of my small dc hosted on AWS. The dc comprises of DEV and PROD environment with a huge list of instances running Java applications. I need to take audit on instances and what they are running. i.e os version, java version etc.

Was thinking to use python + boto3, not sure how much i can do with boto3 in this situation. Or ansible .I will need to ssh into this boxes on the fly, so was thinking ansible.

Any tips, ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in boto3, call the describe-instance to get a dict of all the instances and their private dns addresses and then use something like fabric to go to each box and poll however you wanted to poll. You can use ansible for this and frankly this is probably the best answer long term but you will need to set this up. So the question becomes is this something you are doing one time or do you really need to build more structure here?

If it was me and this needed to be done quickly, I would just use a simple bash one liner calling the aws cli to get the instance id, and private dns entry, then pipe that to a while loop to check you hosts:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, PrivateDnsName]' --output text | while read line ; do echo "=== ${line} ===; prvt_add="$(echo ${line}| awk {'print $2'})"; ssh user@${prvt_add} "echo 'do something' "; echo -e "\n\n";  done
```

Its ugly, but it is also quick. I think I spent 5 mins throwing this together. You might want to add the StrictHostKeyChecking, BatchMode and Timeout options to your ssh call here, but I will leave that to you.

Here is the aws cli page for describe instances, it will show you the information you can play with here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Comment: Thanks Darrell, quite helpful. Will have a go at the ansible option, which i am more familiar with. Also will try ur super long bash one liner to see how it fits and do some tweaking. Also found out i could use fabric to do this, anyway will keep it simple and see how much i can do.